# How to compile a static version of the Monero GUI wallet on macOS

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, build, macos, compile

I have trying to compile the Monero GUI wallet on Mac with the command:

```
make release-static
```

But got this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/boost_system-config.cmake

  but it set boost_system_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_system" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_system-mt.dylib (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)

  * libboost_system-mt.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)
  
  * libboost_system.dylib (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)

  * libboost_system.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /Application/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:166 (find_package)
```

How can I make the static release of the Monero GUI wallet?

**Edit:**
I have installed static versions of all libraries as advised. Now compilation reaches 100% and the error occurs at the final stage of the build.

```
[100%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/monero-wallet-gui.dir/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWebGLIntegrationPlugin_Import.cpp.o 
[100%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/monero-wallet-gui.dir/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QXdgDesktopPortalThemePlugin_Import.cpp.o 
make[3]: stat: /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Gui.a -framework Metal -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGL -framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtlibpng.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5QmlModels.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Qml.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Network.a -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GSS /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework 
DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Network.a -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GSS /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a -framework OpenGL -framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Widgets.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Gui.a -framework Metal -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGL -framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtlibpng.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a -framework OpenGL -framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Gui.a -framework Metal -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGL -framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtlibpng.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a
 /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices 
-framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation 
/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a -framework AppKit -framework OpenGL 
-framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework 
DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security 
-framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework 
CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a 
/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Gui.a -framework Metal -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGL -framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtlibpng.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Widgets.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Gui.a -framework Metal -framework CoreGraphics /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtlibpng.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -framework Metal /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a -framework AppKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework OpenGL -framework AGL /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtlibpng.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a -framework ApplicationServices /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Qml.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Network.a -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GSS /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Network.a -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GSS /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Network.a -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GSS /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libQt5Core.a -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/libqtpcre2.a -framework Security -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GSS -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework AppKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation /usr/local/opt/qt@5
/lib/libqtpcre2.a: File name too long
```

Comment: Did you install a static version of Boost? All the library dependencies need to have their static versions installed if you want to build a statically linked version of Monero.

Comment: Сan you give a link on how to install static libraries for boost and qt5? I spent a lot of time and did not find anything about it

Comment: https://ports.macports.org/port/boost/details/ (includes the static libs, or build boost yourself) and https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/osx-deployment.html (for qt). You're going to need to build/install static versions of *all* the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile / install static versions of all the dependencies to compile a static version of Monero.

The error you are getting is because boost cannot be found, so compile and install boost, and be sure to build / install the static versions.